# c# InstalledFontCollection not showing all fonts like MS Word

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

We are working with `DPL` (Datamax Printing Language) trying to make a `WYSIWYG` editor for printing labels so we would like to use `Datamax` printer fonts.
I have try to list all the fonts installed in the computer using `InstalledFontCollection` but not all fonts are visible.
In MS Word, I can see the fonts:
[image: MS Word example]

What am I missing? Is there any way to list all fonts present in computer?

Comment: MS Word can handle Adobe Type 1 fonts (.pfm). `GDI+` can't. In `WPF`, you have support for Open Type Fonts. In `WinForms`, just True Type or OTF with True Type, even though Windows 8 has added support for OTF CFF in GDI+. GDI does support Type 1 fonts. See here: [Creating a Private Font Collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-creating-a-private-font-collection-use). But System-available and implemented (specific rendering engine) are two differen things. ClearType is the target rendering engine. Most Font tools provide convertion utilities, though.

Comment: I've been making some research and Fonts are not listed in MS Word or WordPad until I print for first time using the printer. So it is some type of driver font substitution.

Comment: Font are probably installed when needed to avoid access violations between the various components that provide print support (Font usage is subject to Security checks). Then, possibly, removed.

Comment: Is it possible to get those fonts from driver and use them in winforms or wpf? I can see fonts in driver options but not in windows Fonts folder (maybe becouse of the install/uninstall).

Comment: They're not necessarily installed in the System Fonts repository. Maybe, in the System Temp folder. If you can get to them in time :), you could try to convert them to True Type and install them as usual.

Comment: Note, however, that GDI+ rendering and the Printer driver rendering may not match at all. No guarantees there.